# Anova Analysis Python_Urgent

Tags: python, database, data-analysis, anova

I hope I can be as clear as possible.
I have an excel file with 400 subjects for a study and for each one of them I have their age, their sex and 40 more columns of biological variables.
Es: CODE0001; (age)20; M\F; Biovalue1; BioValue 2 ..... Biovalue 40.

My goal is to analyze these data with the 1-way Anova because I think it's the best option I have. I'm trying do it (even using this guide https://www.marsja.se/four-ways-to-conduct-one-way-anovas-using-python/ ) but there's always a problem with the code.

So: how can I set up my data in order to be able to use the code for example from that website?

I've already done Dataset.mean() and Dataset.std() for all the data, but I can't use for example the value "Mean Age" because it seems like Jupyter only reads it as a string and not a value.

I'm in a deep state of confusion, so all kind of help will be super appreciated!!!

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

When using `df.mean()` or `df.std()`, try changing the data to `pd.Series` first and run it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but I didn't understand. I'm relatively new to python so maybe i couldn't explain myself properly.
I need to do an Anova analysis:

First I did this:

```
AnalisiISAD.mean()
```

2) Then I made a list from that:

MeanList = [......]
3) Then i proceded with the anova script

```
AnalisiI.boxplot('MeanList', by='AgeT0', figsize=(12,8))

ctrl = Analisi['MeanList'][Analisi == 'ctrl']

grps = pd.unique(Analisi.group.values)

d_data = {grp:Analisi['MeanList'][Analisi.group ==grp] for grp in grps}

k = len(pd.unique(Analisi.group))

N = len(Analisi.values)

n = Analisi.groupby('AgeT0').size()[0]
```

but this error occurs: `KeyError: 'Column not found: MeanList'`

Does this mean I have to create a new column in the excel file? How do I do that?